# Kubuntu 16.04 install on PCIe to M.2 card memory

Tags: boot, kubuntu, uefi, pcie, m2

I'm trying to install Kubuntu 16.04 on M.2 SSD memory, but the memory doesn't seems to be detected at boot time.

I have the following configuration:

- Gigabyte GA-Z68X-UD3H-B3 motherboard. BIOS upgraded to the UEFI bios.
- 120GB ATA OCZ-Vertex3 (SATA600) SSD memory
- Delock PCI Express to M.2 NGFF card

  - with 128GB SM951 PCIe NVMe M.2 SSD memory

The M.2 is not selectable from the bios to boot directly from, but during installation of Kubuntu it is detected as /dev/nvme0n1. The other SSD drive is /dev/sda.

I created a EFI partition on /dev/sda1. When installing Kubuntu on /dev/sda2 I can boot it, but when it is installed on /dev/nvme0n1p1 I get the message "error: no such device ". 
I also tried in Legacy mode using an MBR partition table instead of a GPT partition table, but it gives the same results.

Any idea how I could install Kubuntu on the M.2 drive?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `uname -a`

Comment: If the device is not showing up in the installer, chances are the kernel lacks a driver for it. This problem is not easily overcome, as it may require a newer kernel. Thus, installing 16.10 may be necessary, and even that's not guaranteed to work. It's conceivable that using a non-Ubuntu kernel may work around the problem, but that's a lot of work.

Comment: It does show up in the installer. And the installation process seems to finish correctly. But when I try to boot to the installed system, I get the "error: no such device" error.

Comment: And the output of `uname -a` of the installer is `Linux kubuntu 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`